# No puede resolver simbolo de una variable, Java

Tags: java

java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable orden

Estoy empezando en java, estaba escribiendo un algoritmo para ordenar numeros dependiendo un orden, y la variable orden aunque la uso me dice que no se usa y que no puede resolver simbolo de esa variable.
Siento que es un problema del rango / alcance de la variable pero intento ver donde yace el problema pero no logro verlo..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class C4EJ1C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numeros = new int[3];
        int[] numerosOrdenados = new int[numeros.length];
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            if (args[i].equals("")) {
                numeros[i] = teclado.nextInt();
            } else {
                numeros[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            }
        }
  
//la declado aca

        if (args[3].equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Escriba en que orden desea ordenar (ascendente, descendente)");
            String orden = teclado.nextLine();
        } else {
            String orden = args[3];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            int max = 0;
            int aux = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) {
                if (max < numeros[j]) {
                    max = numeros[j];
                    aux = j;
                }
            }
            numeros[aux] = 0;

//y aca no logro usarla
            if (orden.equals("descendente")) {
                numerosOrdenados[i] = max;
            }
            if (orden.equals("ascendente")) {
                numerosOrdenados[numeros.length - i - 1] = max;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(numerosOrdenados[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Que una variable no sea usada no necesariamente es un problema. Puede que te hayas equivocado de variable o que realmente no sea necesaria en el código.

Comment: Cuando edites, recuerda incluir el mensaje deerror completo. No un resumen, el mensaje o traza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviamente esto no compila..

Tu error, que solo describiste (y deberias haber escrito, siempre pone el error, no tu interpretacion del error), es clarisimo...

donde definiste tu variable orden?

```
if (args[3].equals("")) {
    System.out.println("Escriba en que orden desea ordenar (ascendente, descendente)");
    String orden = teclado.nextLine();
} else {
    String orden = args[3];
}
```

ahi.. .adentro del if... y para variar.. dos veces la definiste ahi...

cuando saliste del if.. puf.. ya no existe.. porque el ambito de esa variable, es dentro de ese if...

Para simplificarte el problema, una variable vive dentro de los corchetes que la contienen, y por supuesto, para abajo...

Comment: Aclarando... cuando el compañero gbianchi dice "para abajo" se refiere a "para adentro"! Una vez que pasas el corchete de cierre del scope de la variable (en este caso, el corchete de cierre del if/else) da igual que estés por debajo del mismo, ya no existe. No hay más que hacer, una vez que sales del corchete que la contiene, no existe :)

Comment: @Benito-B para abajo me referia a los corchetes de mas adentro.. si mejor.. refraseemos...